# libinput/kernel Update Screwed my pointer accel/threshold

Tags: mouse, kernel

So I just got the update to kernel 4.10 and now the touchpad sensitivity has been severely reduced and feels, I can only describe as, sloppy. It now lacks precision and I can't adjust that. Is there is fix for this? Reverting back to kernel 4.8 on boot does not fix this. Neither does moving to 4.12. This might be related to a libinput update that came along with the kernel update.

I've opened a bug report [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1707032). I appears to have messed up the threshold and acceleration settings.

System is Dell Insprion 15 7579 - i7200U i5 Kaby Lake.

Comment: donot work
Linux eney-H81M-HD3 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a permanent fix but a work around for those affected by this.

Go to Settings > Applications > Startup

Hit the + at the bottom right and enter:

```
xset m 3/1 4
```

This will run this command when the system boots and set the mouse speed and acceleration to what it was before the update screwed it up. 3/1 is the acceleration and 4 is the threshold. You can look [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration) for more information on the settings and play around with them until they meet your needs.

Note: The xset output immediately after the update was 5/1 5. So considerably different. What causes the modification I do not know. Hope this helps.