# Touchpad cursor movement less smooth than it used to be

Tags: release-loki, touchpad

Since two days ago, I am experiencing a difference in how one-finger movements on the touchpad are translated into cursor movement. It is less smooth than before, especially when it's just a small movement the cursor seems to resist to move, e.g. when I'm trying to hit a button or something.
What could have caused that? Has there been an update to the driver? If so, how can I revert back to the previous version?

I am using an Asus Zenbook UX305U with elementary OS Loki 0.4.1

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem happened after libinput update. This is my apt log after this update: https://pastebin.com/Aq8QFpVW

Comment: I am experiencing something similar. It happens in conjunction with the upgrade to kernel 4.10. So it began for me a few days ago. I've submitted a bug report on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1707032) and have a thread on the forum [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12824/libinput-kernel-update-screwed-my-pointer-accel-threshold).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to downgrade HWE graphical stack to Xenial default (however, it will be maintained until 2021).

**Be careful and follow these commands at your own risk!**

Firstly, you should remove HWE graphical packages:

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04
```

This command will remove Xorg and `elementary-desktop` metapackage. In total 19 or 20 packages will be removed. Then, install older version of Xorg and reinstall `elementary-desktop` metapackage (don't reboot your PC before running this command!):

```
sudo apt install elementary-desktop xserver-xorg-core
```

Reboot and enjoy ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the post! Do you have a source for this solution?

Comment: I gave it a shot and it worked. Not 100%, but it certainly improved the mouse function. Then I ran "xset m 10/1 20" and it's much better. So I'm about 90% of what the touchpad was before. Not perfect, but will just take some getting used too. Thank so much!

Comment: Nevermind. After some time in suspend it now has disabled the touchpad. Reboot doesn't help. Going to try a reinstall and don't adjusting the sensitivity and acceleration settings through the terminal.

Comment: Source? There is no source.

Comment: I mean where do you find the solution. Not source code :)

Comment: @SeanPatterson I understood what you mean, I myself found this solution :)

Answer (score -1):

you have to delete the synaptic conf files in the /usr/share/X11 directory then reboot. update switched to libinput so the synaptic files are unneeded/hindering it.

Comment: You're going to need to give more information than that for the sake of others, such as how to delete the files and what files to delete specifically. Also, isn't this something that could be handled `apt --purge packagename`?